# ! Bad space factor (0)

Tags: xetex, errors, latexmk

When trying to compile my `.tex` file using the `latexmk -latex=xelatex` command, I receive the following error:

```
! Bad space factor (0).
<recently read> \@savsf 

l.39 \end{seriate}

?
```

Then, if I press return, the compilation process resumes with no apparent negative outcome. The output is just correct. I don't see why I get this, but the error doesn't let me streamline the compilation process.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,man]{apa6}  
\usepackage[american]{babel}  
\usepackage{csquotes}  
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}  
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}  
\usepackage{graphics}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}  
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}  
\setmonofont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}

\begin{seriate}  
\item a scientific experiment,   
\item the presence of an  
\end{seriate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Werner and Boris. Here is my MWE. I haven't tried removing the packages one by one, because I am a newbie and I don't know what exactly each of them does. I guess the problem is related to the APA6 document class that redefines "Seriate", but that's just a wild guess. Thank you again in advance for your generosity and helpfulness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `seriate` environment is supposed to be used in mid paragraph. Add `\leavevmode` in front of it if you want to start a paragraph with it:

```
\leavevmode\begin{seriate}  
\item a scientific experiment,   
\item the presence of an  
\end{seriate}
```

On the other hand, text such as

```
We present
\begin{seriate}
\item a rabbit,
\item a fox,
\end{seriate}
and look at what happens
```

should not give problems.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you copied and pasted some code which contained "internal" LaTeX structures.  This *is* possible and allowed, but as another layer of protection of users from themselves such code contains the symbol "@" in command names etc.  To make this code work you need to precede it with `\makeatletter` and it is a good idea to finish it with `\makeatother`

```
\makeatletter
CODE
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks Werner and Boris. Here is my MWE. I haven't tried removing the packages one by one, because I am a newbie and I don't know what exactly each of them does. I guess the problem is related to the APA6 document class that redefines "Seriate", but that's just a wild guess. Thank you again in advance for your generosity and helpfulness.