# Error "Bad space factor (0)." when using \input to generate file name for VerbatimOut

Tags: verbatim, input

I want to output some text, verbatim, to `$TMPDIR/myFile.txt`, then do some other operations with that file.

Note: to allow LaTeX to write to files outside the current folder, you need to:

- Run LaTeX with `--shell-escape` to allow for `\input`
- Add `openout_any=a` to `texmf.cnf` to allow writing to any folder (findable in a terminal via `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`)

I'm trying to obtain the real file path via `\input{|echo $TMPDIR/myFile.txt}` as per:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252957/how-to-execute-shell-script-from-latex

with complete minimal repro:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myFile}{\immediate\input{|echo $TMPDIR/myFile.txt}}
\begin{VerbatimOut}{\myFile}
my file contents here <> {} () $ "" ''.
\end{VerbatimOut}
% ... do something on disk with \myFile

\end{document}
```

However, this generates an error `Bad space factor (0).` on the `\end{VerbatimOut}` line.

Possibly related:
[! Bad space factor (0)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41195/bad-space-factor-0)
but that answer (`\leavevmode`) sounds specific to `seriate`.

Why is this error generated, and is there a way to accomplish the above goal?

Comment: probably unrelated but remove `\immediate` from `\immediate\input`

Comment: latex `\input`  is not expandable so `\myFile` does not expand to a file name so `\begin{VerbatimOut}{\myFile}` can not work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how does someone determine if a particular function is expandable or not?
Looking online for `\input`, I found various pages describing its functionality, but none mentioned its expandability.

When something isn't expandable and is misused, it tends to cause poor errors.

Should people just assume that everything isn't expandable, and only use `expl3` definitions when expandable functions are required?

Comment: Martin Scharrer's answer on the following post states "You can use `\input` basically everywhere with any content." and "You can nest `\input` macros.", which is pretty confusing, since it isn't expandable.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Comment: it says `The LaTeX version of \input only does some sanity checks and then...`  those checks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\sys_get_shell:nnN` of `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\getfromshell}{mO{}m}
 {% #1 = command, #2 = setup, #3 = control sequence
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { #1 } { #2 } #3
  \tl_trim_spaces:N #3
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\getfromshell{kpsewhich -expand-var=$TMPDIR/myfile.txt}{\myfile}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_analysis_show:N \myfile
\ExplSyntaxOff

\texttt{\myfile}% just to test

\end{document}
```

Spaces are trimmed off at either end. I'd prefer `kpsewhich -expand-var` so it's system independent *and* doesn't require shell escape.

You can pass `\myfile` to `VerbatimOut`, of course. I tested it with the call

```bash
TMPDIR=foo pdflatex davidfink
```

(I gave a different value to `TMPDIR` just not to get overlong output like `/var/folders/8b/hx9v58ln1txgzv4v32_vpbr40000gq/T/`)
and the console shows

```
The token list \myfile contains the tokens:
>  f (the letter f)
>  o (the letter o)
>  o (the letter o)
>  / (the character /)
>  m (the letter m)
>  y (the letter y)
>  f (the letter f)
>  i (the letter i)
>  l (the letter l)
>  e (the letter e)
>  . (the character .)
>  t (the letter t)
>  x (the letter x)
>  t (the letter t).
```

Finally

[image]

is printed.

The full syntax is

```
\getfromshell{<command line>}[<setup>]<control sequence>
```

The `<setup>` argument can be used for setting category codes in case of special characters returned by the `<command line>`.

Comment: `TMPDIR` is a standard environment variable and usually TeX programs are not allowed to write in the directory it points to.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX `\input` uses `\@ifnextchar` and is not expandable. You can use the primitive.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myFile}{\@@input"|echo myFile.txt" }
\makeatother
\begin{VerbatimOut}{\myFile}
my file contents here <> {} () $ "" ''.
\end{VerbatimOut}
% ... do something on disk with \myFile

\end{document}
```